# Refreshing contents of a Modal Dialogue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a row of buttons on a web page, each of which is to invoke a Model dialogue to display further details. I am displaying the modal dialogue thus:-

```
winArgs = window.showModalDialog('MyDialogue.aspx', winArgs, winSettings);
```

and when I do this, the codebehind detects the data it is supposed to display and displays it on the Modal dialogue. I then close this down with the red X, and click another button to display a different dataset, but no codebehind methods are invoked, and consequently the dialogue displays the previous dataset.

I guess there is nothing that can be done about this on closing (that is a client event), so what I need to know is how do I either:-

create a new modal dialogue with the `showModalDialog` and not re-use the existing one,

or, invoke some function in the code-behind when the dialogue pops up?

Comment: When you say dialog, do you mean the jQuery UI Dialog, or the old school new window?

Comment: @MelanciaUK, the old school new window; I don't knowingly have any jQuery in the application.

Comment: I see. I mentioned that because it would be way easier if you did. You could have a play with an UpdatePanel within the jQuery dialog (which can be achieved using native Javascript aswell). In other words, you would have way more control over what's going on, because everything would be in the same window.

Comment: I found by accident that adding an asp:TextBox causes the code-behind to be invoked as often as one could desire. When I posted the question the dialogue had only asp:Labels in it. I suppose this could by a great stretch of the imagination be called a solution.

Comment: I've never heard about this kind of thing. Haha